Predicing next customers purchase dates (and possibly amount)
I have a dataset with simple list of customer, date of purchase, amount. I'd like to predict the next purchase date for each customer and possibly the amount.



Customer
Date of Purchase
Amount




A
05/05/2024
100000


A
16/05/2024
50000


B
05/05/2024
75000


B
05/06/2024
75000



Some customers buy something each month, others twice a month and so on. In some period of the years, customers have different peaks where they buy significantly more. For example, some customers buy much more things in summer, others in winter, or on specific month.
What I tried unsuccessfully : auto arima and prophet
I tried to train a model using python auto arima wich poor result. I also tried facebook prophet. It seems that those models are not the best when dealing with such sporadic data? They give me an amount for each date to predict and I tried to filter only the "peak" dates.
Could you share with me some suitable models for that kind of goal?
